# Batch command move png files to folders same name files and folders

Tags: batch-file

I want to move png files to folders same name files and folders using batch dos.

```
Example:-
abc <= folder 
adc.png          => abc\abc.png

abc1 <= folder 
adc1.png          => abc1\abc1.png

a b c <= folder 
a d c.png          => a b c\a b c.png

A b c D <= folder 
A b c D.png          => A b c D\A b c D.png

etc.
```

Comment: Please format you directory tree in an easier to understand manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /F "Tokens=* delims=" %%I in ('dir /a-d /b *.png') do (
   mkdir "%%~nI"
   move "%%~I" "%%~nI/%%~I"
)
```

Something like this...

Comment: Note this will only work if type in cmd. You need to double the `%` signs

Comment: File Not Found     :(